# Как заархивировать файлы, пришедшие с фронта?

Tags: c#

На фронте (vue) собираю файлы в FormData и отправляю с помощью axios на бэк (C#)

А дальше уже сложности так как ни разу не бэкэндэр.
Нужно файлы заархивировать и вернуть на клиент архив.
Как это можно сделать?

Смотрел ZipFile, но он принимает на Вход адрес и имя файла.
Можно ли выполнить задачу на сохраняя файлы на серверную машину ?

Comment: Вот какой-то древний вопрос на английском СО https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232414/creating-a-zip-archive-in-memory-using-system-io-compression Можно из потока заархивировать.

Comment: Сама фраза «ссылку на скачивание архива» подразумевает, что где-то неизбежно придётся хранить файл до тех пор, пока эту самую ссылку не откроют

Comment: А если нужно реализовать возможность докачки и посещения ссылки несколько раз, то придётся хранить файл вообще вечность. Так что если вы не хотите ничего хранить — для начала переформулируйте задачу так, чтобы она по сути своей не требовала хранения чего-либо

Comment: @andreymal подправил текст. Нужно просто вернуть ахив.

Comment: @VadimTregubenko На беке ASP.NET используется? В каком виде данные доступны с бека? 
Если ASP.NET, то покажи сигнатуру метода контроллера.

Comment: @Nyuhnyash да, ASP.NET c CQRS. Буду благодарен